# Como insertar un valor que empieza por '@' sin que sea reconocido como parámetro en MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql

Estoy intentando insertar una lista de datos en una tabla MySQL.
Debido a temas de rendimiento, estoy rellenando una `List<string>` y con esta lista genero mi comando para insertar todas las filas en un unico INSERT.

Aquí está mi código:

```
StringBuilder cmdText = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO my_Table (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES ");

        List<string> aux = new List<string>();

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                aux.Add(string.Format("('{0}','{1}')", row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToSTring()));
            }

            cmdText.Append(string.Join(",", aux));
            cmdText.Append(";");
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText.ToString(), conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            };
```

De esta manera, mi comando finalmente quedaría en el siguiente formato:

```
INSERT INTO my_Table (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES ('Value1','Value2'),('Value3','Value4') ...;
```

La lista tiene aproximadamente 500K filas.

Algunos valores de las filas que quiero insertar empiezan por '@'

No estoy usando parámetros pero al arrancar mi aplicación,
me lanza el siguiente error:

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.
>   "Parameter '@GMAIL.COM' must be defined."

'@gmail.com' es una valor y no un parámetro, pero MySQL lo interpreta como si fuese un @parametro.

**Alguien sabe cómo indicar que ES un valor y NO un parámetro?**

**Hay alguna otra manera de "escapar" el valor '@' para que no lo reconozca como parámetro?**

Comment: Yo me ahorraría todo este problema no guardando el '@', sabemos que es un carácter que se utiliza para hacer referencia a parámetros. La otra opcion es la que deja @RandallSandoval que transformas obviamente el caracter para poder guardarlo sin problema y cuando lo utilices lo vuelves a transformar para visualizarlo correctamente.

Comment: Como te hemos dicho en stack overflow, hay que utilizar consultas parametrizadas. No hay ninguna razón para que vayan mas lentas que utilizando concatenación de cadenas.

Comment: lo sé @Pikoh, pero cómo ya dije, de la otra manera se me va a 3 horas, y lo unico que cambia de este código al otro es que en el otro hago el ExecuteNonQuery() dentro del loop y hago un Paramaters.Clear() para que en cada iteración me coja los valores de la fila correspondiente. No creo que eso sea lo que hace que se me vaya a 3 horas. también sé que hacer concatenaciones para lanzar query es una práctica que me expone a SQL INJECTIONS pero también es cierto que UN UNICO INSERT con 500K paquetes es mucho más ÓPTIMO que 500K INSERTS.

Comment: Busco rendimiento más que seguridad, porque no es una aplicación que vaya a ir a producción.

Comment: ..... de momento

Comment: Lo entiendo, aunque me parece una aberración un insert con 500K values :) Yo le echaria un vistazo a [esta clase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx), es posible que haga lo que necesitas sin necesidad de exponerte

Comment: Adhiero a Pikoh: preparedstatements gana en todo: prolijidad, seguridad y tambien rendimiento (la consulta se compila una sola vez)

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh ya usé esta clase en su día cuando trabajé con SQL SERVER y rinde MUY BIEN, pero en C# esta clase no se puede usar para volcar en bases de datos MySQL. y la librería MySql.Data.MySqlClient de .NET no tiene ninguna clase BulkCopy por desgracia.

Comment: Vaya,no me di cuenta que era MySQL. Pero de todas maneras, existe [MySqlBulkLoader](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html) que no he usado pero tiene pinta de ser similar a SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: gracias @Pikoh la verdad es que sí, parece que es bastante similar a un SqlBulkCopy. De todos modos, si alguien quisiera insertar un valor con @ ya sea concatenando o sin concatenar, debería haber una manera de escapar este carácter. Muchas gracias por el interés de todas formas, se agradece :)

Answer (score 3):

La opción más recomendada es utilizar queries parametrizadas como lo recomienda Randall Sandoval, ya que con ellas evitas inyecciones SQL. Pero debes también especificar esos parámetros en la conexión. Trata algo así:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@miParametro1", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row[0].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@miParametro2", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row[1].ToString();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        };
```

Tal vez por ahí me falte manejar las rows, pero ese debe solucionar el problema

Answer (score 1):

Una opción sería usar la Función `CHAR()`, pues este devuelve el caracter según el código ASCII que le ingreses; [aquí](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-char-function.php) hay más información sobre esta opción.

Entonces deberías hacer un [REPLACE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiCjemQn9PQAhVEKyYKHemlAZ8QFggjMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fes-es%2Flibrary%2Ffk49wtc1(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHUU4-pgM4V3nAOGk-Th8r7zY8DPw&sig2=9bwd4iooieR_m09RbSUs1Q&bvm=bv.139782543,d.eWE&cad=rja) en tu cadena, cambiando cada @ por CHAR(64).

```
String query = "INSERT INTO my_Table (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES ('miParametro1','miParametro2'),('@miParametro3','miParametro4')";
query.Replace("'@", "CHAR(64)+'");
```

Quedado el query de la siguiente forma

> INSERT INTO my_Table (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES
>   ('miParametro1','miParametro2'),(CHAR(64)+'miParametro3','miParametro4')

Así quedaría el Código

```
StringBuilder cmdText = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO my_Table (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES ");

        List<string> aux = new List<string>();

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                aux.Add(string.Format("('{0}','{1}')", row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToSTring()));
            }

            cmdText.Append(string.Join(",", aux));
            cmdText.Append(";");
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText.ToString().Replace("'@", "CHAR(64)+'"), conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            };
```

Espero te sirva esta información

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, entiendo lo que me quieres decir pero en este caso estaría reemplazando el valor, y lo que realmente me interesa es poder insertarlo tal como me viene, empiece por '@' o no.

Comment: si hiciera esto, ¿al visualizar los datos me apereceria el arroba? o tendría que hacer alguna transformación, como apunta "sioesi" ?

Comment: No estarías reemplazando todo el valor, solo es cambiar el caracter @ por su equivalente en la función `CHAR`, Por ejemplo es lo mismo querer insertar '@gmail.com' que insertar CHAR(64)+'gmail.com'

Comment: Se aparecería el @, haz la prueba desde la línea de comando de MySQL `INSERT INTO my_Table (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES (CHAR(64)+'parametroConArroba','@parametroConArroba')` y verás que los dos tienen el arroba al principio

Comment: En la opción que yo te doy no existe ninguna alteración, se guardar el @ porque sí tu lo ves yo cambio '@ por CHAR(64)+', entonces solo se concatena el resultado de la función al resto del texto ya existente

Comment: la solución que dices, me arroja este error: 

> Incorrect truncated DOUBLE value 'parametroConArroba'

Comment: lo que no acabo de entender es porque si inserto un valor que empieza por @ desde el cliente MySQL me deja, y desde mi aplicación no,¿Por qué?

Comment: Ya actualicé, te puse como quedaría quedar, copia exactamente la linea del using, y dime sí te da el mismo error

Answer (score 1):

En tu cadena de conexión agrega `;Allow User Variables=True`

Esto te permitirá la interacción con la base de datos sin que tengas que modificar tu código

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero ya probé esta opción y entonces me da el mismo tipo de error pero haciendo referencia a los valores que empiezan por '?' tal y como se declaran las variables de usuario.

Comment: la pregunta tiene que ver con cómo escapar un caracter especial, tu respuesta no está relacionada.

Comment: Es totalmente relacionada ya que el resultado de la ejecución de ese script en la base de datos infiere directamente con el parámetro de configuración

Comment: Tal vez, pero no contestaste específicamente cómo escapar el caracter, que es la duda principal :)

Comment: Mi respuesta no se basa específicamente en como escapar el caracter, estoy dando una solución alterna

Comment: aunque tu método corrija el problema, te estás saliendo por la tangente. Además no le estás explicando el impacto que esto lleva y por ello tu respuesta no está completa. Que tengas buen día.

Comment: No veo alguna cláusula en SOes dónde diga que es necesario dar una respuesta de lo que se pregunta, justo para eso es el foro, para dar diferentes soluciones a un problema

Comment: @Flxtr en realidad esa es la razón primordial del sitio y la esencia de que las respuestas sean lo que son: responder primero a la pregunta. Lo demás, por más información positiva que sea, son adicionales.

Answer (score -3):

La ironía es que la causa del error es *precisamente* debido a que optaste por concatenar el SQL mas bien que usar parámetros. Debido a esto, caíste en una trampa que a menudo sucede cuando se hace esto.

El error no es causado porque MySQL esté interpretando el símbolo `@` dentro de un valor como un parámetro. Mas bien, es debido a que no has construido el SQL correctamente.

Para comprobarlo, intenta el siguiente ejemplo

Asumiendo que tienes una tabla así:

```sql
create table tbl (
  col varchar(50)
)
```

Ahora prueba el código siguiente:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into tbl (col) values ('pete@gmail.com')", conn))
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Como podrás comprobar, el código funciona perfectamente.

En contraste, prueba el código siguiente (nota el `'` adicional antes del `@`):

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into tbl (col) values ('pete'@gmail.com')", conn))
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Este código lanza el error siguiente:

> Fatal error encountered during command execution. --> Parameter '@gmail.com' must be defined.

... y allí esta el problema. Por concatenar los valores directamente al SQL, debes tener comillas simples que no has escapado correctamente, lo que resulta en un SQL inválido que causa confusión con el símbolo `@`.

Para remediar el problema inmediato, puedes escapar las comillas simples usando `string.Replace`:

```
aux.Add(string.Format("('{0}','{1}')", row[0].ToString().Replace("'", "''"), row[1].ToString().Replace("'", "''")));
```

Pero la verdadera solución es la que te han repetido en los comentarios y respuestas: parametrizar la consulta.

**Edición**

Yo sigo pensando (a pesar de los votos negativos) que tienes un problema con las comillas, porque un SQL bien construído no genera el error que reportas.

Y la comilla adicional ni siquiera tiene que aparecer en el campo que te da error.

Por ejemplo, intenta la prueba siguiente:

```
string insertText = "insert into my_Table (ColumnA, ColumnB) values ('una comilla ' perdida', 'abc'), ('@gmail.com', 'zzz')";
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertText, conn))
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Cuando yo lo pruebo, recibo un error idéntico al tuyo:

> Fatal error encountered during command execution. ---> Parameter '@gmail.com' must be defined.

Y sin embargo, el valor `'@gmail.com'` se ve correcto. Pero el problema está en el valor anterior: `'una comilla ' perdida'` que tiene una comilla sin escapar que tiene por efecto de corromper la cadena SQL entera.

Ahora bien, como tu cadena SQL es sumamente larga, es muy fácil que no te des cuenta que alguna comilla no está escapada. Y nuevamente, el problema de la comilla no sucede necesariamente con el valor `'@gmail.com'` mismo.

Como te sugerí arriba, prueba agregando el `.Replace("'", "''")` a los valores, y ve si no te arregla el problema, por lo menos para comprobar si es o no es esto la causa del problema.

Pero, pero evitar este tipo de problemas y otros más, piensa seriamente en parametrizar la consulta.

**Cómo parametrizar tu `INSERT`**

Basándome en tu código existente, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo pudieras modificarlo para que la consulta quede parametrizada:

```
StringBuilder cmdText = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO my_Table (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES ");

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            if (i != 0)
            {
                cmdText.Append(", ");
            }

            string columnAParameterName = $"@ColumnA{i}";
            string columnBParameterName = $"@ColumnB{i}";

            cmdText.Append($"({columnAParameterName}, {columnBParameterName})");

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(columnAParameterName, row[0].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(columnBParameterName, row[1].ToString());

            i++;
        }

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = cmdText.ToString();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: MUychas gracias por tu respuesta, pero no es asi 100% ya que el SQL está bien construido. No és que me coja 'pete'@gmail.com' como muestras en el ejemplo. HE comprobado manualmente ese campo y el campo integramente tiene valor --> @GMAIL.COM

Comment: @Pete: Aunque esté equivocado en cuanto a la causa de tu error, si no vas a parametrizar la consulta, vas a tener que hacer el `.Replace()` para manejar las comillas por si aparecieran en los valores. ¿Has probado hacerlo para ver que pasa? Adicionalmente, ¿has intentado una prueba sencilla con un solo valor de `insert into ... values ('@GMAIL.COM')` para ver si te funciona o no? Porque yo no puedo reproducir tu error en ese caso.

Comment: Le agregué a mi respuesta otra variante del mismo problema de comillas que reproduce tu error. Yo sigo convencido que lo que te sucede es el problema clásico de la comilla no escapada.